# How java.net package works?

Tags: java, android, linux

Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html) describes the `java.net` package to be use for networking by apps. Now Android has a Linux kernel, so eventually any HTTP request made by the package has to translate into some system call.

What I want to ask is whether this library also ships with some JNI layer code, and does it rely on libc library to interact with the kernel ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Android source code tree to find out?

Comment: It will call the BSD Sockets API via a JNI layer. No other way it can work.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle JVM **net.dll** is loaded inside AbstractPlainSocketImpl which is present in **jre/bin**.

```
/**
 * Load net library into runtime.
 */
static {
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                System.loadLibrary("net");
                return null;
            }
        });
}
```

Android's Dalvik also works the same way. Take a look at the following links:

https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/tree/master/libcutils
https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/libcutils/socket_network_client.c